# Ударение в словах "йогурт" и "логин"

Tags: фонетика

Как правильно ставить ударение в словах "йогурт" и "логин"?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно — йОгурт, логИн (правда, Лопатин допускает и вариант "йогУрт").